# Content-Type HTTP application/x-www-form-urlencoded is return error

Tags: magento2, rest-api, webapi

When i am using Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in API i getting the error:

```
{
  "message": "Server cannot understand Content-Type HTTP header media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "trace": null
}
```

With Content-Type: "application/json" this works, but is necessary too with application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

I add deserializer in app/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\DeserializerFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="deserializers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="application_json" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">application/json</item>
                    <item name="model" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Deserializer\Json</item>
                </item>
                <item name="application_xml" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">application/xml</item>
                    <item name="model" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Deserializer\Xml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="application_xhtml_xml" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">application/xhtml+xml</item>
                    <item name="model" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Deserializer\Xml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="text_xml" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">text/xml</item>
                    <item name="model" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Deserializer\Xml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="application_x_www_form_urlencoded" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">application/x-www-form-urlencoded</item>
                    <item name="model" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Deserializer\Json</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

And get this response:

```
{
  "message": "The \"string\" value's type is invalid. The \"string[]\" type was expected. Verify and try again.",
  "trace": null
}
```

This is possible? And why Magento 2 not support application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a separate file for content type urlencoded

```
<?php
/**
 * FormUrlencoded deserializer of REST request content.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Webapi\Rest\Request\Deserializer;

use InvalidArgumentException;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Parameters;
use Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\DeserializerInterface;

/**
 * Class FormUrlencoded
 */
class FormUrlencoded implements DeserializerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Parameters
     */
    private $parameters;
    /**
     * @var State
     */
    protected $_appState;
    /**
     * FormUrlencoded constructor.
     * @param Parameters $parameters
     * @param State $appState
     */
    public function __construct(
        Parameters $parameters,
        State $appState
    ) {
        $this->parameters = $parameters;
        $this->_appState = $appState;
    }

    /**
     * Parse Request body into array of params.
     *
     * @param string $encodedBody Posted content from request.
     * @return array|null Return NULL if content is invalid.
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception If decoding error was encountered.
     */
    public function deserialize($encodedBody)
    {
        if (!is_string($encodedBody)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                sprintf('"%s" data type is invalid. String is expected.', gettype($encodedBody))
            );
        }
        try {
            $decodedBody = urldecode($encodedBody);
            $this->parameters->fromString($decodedBody);
            return $this->parameters->toArray();
        } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            if ($this->_appState->getMode() !== State::MODE_DEVELOPER) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception(new Phrase('Decoding error.'));
            } else {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception(
                    new Phrase(
                        'Decoding error: %1%2%3%4',
                        [PHP_EOL, $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL, $e->getTraceAsString()]
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```